# Multiple-entry visa living duration

Tags: visas, singapore

I have 2 year multiple-entry visa for Singapore so I want to know how many days I can stay continuously legally in Singapore and can I work over there legally if I get an agreement from a company

Comment: What kind of visa is it ? By multiple I assume you mean multiple-entry ?

Comment: I would also edit out the part about working there because that's off-topic on this site